# Ejecutar Update en Fireird si se cumple una condición que esta en otra tabla

Tags: select, update, firebird, exists, where

La condición me trae todos los registros.

UPDATE
V3RELACION_ENTRADAS_COSTOS_LOTE
SET
V3RELACION_ENTRADAS_COSTOS_LOTE.PRECIO_MAXIMO = (V3RELACION_ENTRADAS_COSTOS_LOTE.COSTO_CALCULADO + ((15*V3RELACION_ENTRADAS_COSTOS_LOTE.COSTO_CALCULADO)/100))
WHERE (EXISTS(SELECT PRODUCTOS_TERMINADOS.CODIGO_PRODUCTO FROM PRODUCTOS_TERMINADOS
INNER JOIN  V3RELACION_ENTRADAS_COSTOS_LOTE
ON PRODUCTOS_TERMINADOS.CODIGO_PRODUCTO = V3RELACION_ENTRADAS_COSTOS_LOTE.PRODUCTO_CODIGO
WHERE PRODUCTOS_TERMINADOS.DEPARTAMENTO_CODIGO <> '  -  01-11') )

Si ejecuto el select solo trae los registros correspondientes
SELECT PRODUCTOS_TERMINADOS.CODIGO_PRODUCTO FROM PRODUCTOS_TERMINADOS
INNER JOIN  V3RELACION_ENTRADAS_COSTOS_LOTE
ON PRODUCTOS_TERMINADOS.CODIGO_PRODUCTO = V3RELACION_ENTRADAS_COSTOS_LOTE.PRODUCTO_CODIGO
WHERE PRODUCTOS_TERMINADOS.DEPARTAMENTO_CODIGO <> '  -  01-11'

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionar empleando MERGE, el código quedó así:

**MERGE INTO V3RELACION_ENTRADAS_COSTOS_LOTE AS B
USING PRODUCTOS_TERMINADOS AS A
ON A.CODIGO_PRODUCTO = B.PRODUCTO_CODIGO AND DEPARTAMENTO_CODIGO <> '  -  01-11'
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET B.PRECIO_MAXIMO = (B.COSTO_CALCULADO + ((50*B.COSTO_CALCULADO)/100))**